# how to set a Background image for a bootstrap table

Tags: css, background-image, bootstrap-table

This is the question concerned

I have tried a lot with this method but unfortunately couldn't find a 
    solution.

so *felt to ask this* question after along search in 
       net.*

```
   =====================================================================
   Is there any way to make an image go backside of the table and looks 
   like only image visible and table behind on the image itself.
   code will be like this*

    Aim: To have an image as a background for a table which is 
    developed under bootstrap. 
    -------------------------------------
    The preferred result should look like this
     link:https://jsfiddle.net/39mdqkz2/4/
```

Example of output how it should look: [jsfiddle.net/39mdqkz2/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/39mdqkz2/4/)

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly but this appears to work:

```
table {
    background-size: 3096px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("http://questromworld.bu.edu/studyabroad/files/2014/07/Luc-Australia-Beach.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but actually it is not working with bootstrap table!!! it only works with html table tag. can any one suggest me exact solution or example with a bootstrap table having a background image

Answer (score 1):

By default bootstrap-table doesn't apply any background styling (it's transparent) except for the table-hover class, which colors the background of the row the mouse pointer is currently hovering over. Instead of styling ALL tables with the `table` CSS selector, I'd suggest using the same selector you use to initialize the bootstrap-table with:

**HTML**

```
<table id="tableWithBgImage">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Additional rows removed for brevity -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I removed the classes from your JSFiddle example...`table-striped` will cause alternate rows to be colored (which isn't working in your JSFiddle because there is no CSS for that class). `table-bordered` is a default in bootstrap-table, so it is redundant and can be omitted. I also created an ID to initialize the bootstrap-table with as well as apply specific styling. I removed `cellspacing` because it is redundant with a bootstrap-table, which by default doesn't have any cell spacing. Finally, I removed the height/width attributes in favor of specifying that using CSS.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tableWithBgImage").bootstrapTable(
        // Set the initial classes for the table
        // This removes the bootstrap-table default inclusion of 'table-hover'
        // to prevent rows from being highlighted on hover. Add 'table-hover' to the
        // list if you want to re-enable this
        classes: "table"
    );
});
```

The `classes` option sets the initial class names when bootstrap-table initializes.

**CSS**

```
#tableWithBgImage {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('http://questromworld.bu.edu/studyabroad/files/2014/07/Luc-Australia-Beach.jpg');
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

If you *still* are not getting the background image in your bootstrap-table, then you must have other CSS somewhere that is coloring the table, or otherwise obfuscating the background image of the table. If that's the case, and if possible, it'd help us to see your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for the bootstrap-table in question.